If gradient is bounded then absolute difference in images is bounded
I'm studying mathematical analysis, in particular multivariable differentials. One of the excersises of my book (Pagani-Salsa Analisi Matematica 1), state, Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function, and $\vert{\nabla f(\mathbb{x})}\vert \leq K \in \mathbb{R}$ for all $\mathbb{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ (where $\vert \cdot \vert $ is the norm $\sum_{i =1} ^{n}\nabla f(x)_i$ for each $i$-th component of the gradient, or every other vector), then for every $\mathbb{x,y} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ $\vert f(\mathbb{y})- f(\mathbb{x})\vert \leq K\vert \mathbb{y}-\mathbb{x} \vert $.
Now my attempt is:
By the mean value theorem in more than one dimension there exists a number $\theta $  such that $df(\mathbb{x})(\theta) = \frac{f(\mathbb{y})-f(\mathbb{x})}{\mathbb{y} - \mathbb{x}}$ and so
$\vert f(\mathbb{y})-f(\mathbb{x})\vert = \vert df(\mathbb{x})(\theta) \mathbb{y} - \mathbb{x}\vert = \vert \langle \nabla f(x), \theta\rangle(\mathbb{y} - \mathbb{x})\vert = \vert \nabla f (x)\vert\vert \langle w,\theta\rangle(\mathbb{y} - \mathbb{x})\vert \leq K\vert \langle w,\theta\rangle(\mathbb{y} - \mathbb{x})\vert$ , where $w$ is a unitary vector that point in the same direction of the gradient. Now clearly if $\langle w, \theta \rangle \leq 1$ the theorem is proven but when this dot product is greater than $1$ the difference is clearly bounded but not by $K$. How can i go on?
